# Specifying order of factors in legend when plotted data comes from two separate data frames.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where some variables always have negative values and some always have positive values. I want to make a stacked area plot where the negative values are stacked below the x axis and the positive values above. I have the variable names as factors in a specific order in my data frame which I want to appear in the legend. The problem is that, in order to plot data both above and below the x axis, I have to use geom_area() twice, once with a positive subset of my data, and once with the negative subset. When I do this, it realphabetizes the factors in the legend, disregarding their original order.

```
include('ggplot2')

test <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1,2,3,4),4), 
                   fact=factor(c(rep('a',4),rep('b',4),rep('c',4),rep('d',4)), 
                               levels=c('c','a','d','b'), ordered=TRUE), 
                   y=c(4,3,2,1,-4,-3,-2,-1,8,6,4,2,-8,-6,-4,-2))

# The legend displays the factors in the order I want (c,a,b,d)
ggplot(data=test, mapping=aes(x=x, y=abs(y)))+
  geom_area(mapping=aes(fill=fact))

# This doesn't work for plotting above and below the x axis, 
# so I have to split it into two different geom_area calls.
ggplot(data=test, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_area(mapping=aes(fill=fact))

# Factors in legend are now reordered alphabetically, 
# but I want them to be ordered c,a,b,d.
ggplot(data=test, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_area(data=test[test$y<0,], mapping=aes(fill=fact), stat='identity')+
  geom_area(data=test[test$y>0,], mapping=aes(fill=fact), stat='identity')
```

How can I get the factors in the legend to appear as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually specify the `breaks`:

```
+ scale_fill_hue(breaks = c('c','a','b','d'))
```